# Html Input type is not working

Tags: c#, html

Hi I am using  input type text in login page but in aspx.cs page is not working 
input control give the error. here is my .aspx Page-

```
<input type="text" id="txtloginname" name="txtloginname" required value="Username" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Username'"
                                                   onfocus="if(this.value=='Username')this.value='' " /></p>
```

and Here is my aspx.cs page

```
 SessionInfo.LoginName = txtloginname.Value.Trim();
 SessionInfo.DisplayName = txtloginname.Value.Trim();
```

it gives the error Like --

> The name 'txtloginname' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Hi can you solve this

Comment: You're missing the runat="server" attribute

Comment: i have no need of runat="server"

Comment: Hi Everyone i have no need of runat="server" without runat="server" it is possible or not

Comment: If you want to access in server side code using txtloginname.Value you need runat=server, if you don't add this you may be able to access through Request.Forms["txtLoginName"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input type "text" is pure html control, it is not available in server side. If you want these in server side, Add attribute runat="server" and in server side you can find these control as html Control.

if it is in master page do the following

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText txtLogin = this.Master.FindControl("FeaturedContent").FindControl("txtloginname") as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText;
```

not in master page

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText txtLogin = this.FindControl("txtloginname") as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText;

SessionInfo.LoginName = txtLogin.Value.Trim();
 SessionInfo.DisplayName = txtLogin.Value.Trim();
```

OR

You can use jquery onchange event to get the textbox value and assign it to a asp hidden field, Now the hidden field with the textbox value is available in server side.

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways of doing this for getting the value of input type in aspx page.

1)code for aspx page

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
Name:
<input type="text" id="txtName" name="Name" value="Username" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Username'"
                                               onfocus="if(this.value=='Username')this.value='' " />
<br />
Email:
<input type="text" id="txtEmail" runat="server" value="" />
<br />
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="Submit" />
```

In aspx.cs page code

```
 protected void Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = Request.Form["Name"];
    string email = txtEmail.Value;
}
```

there are two text boxes in example and two ways to get text value .

you can use any one you like

**you are getting error because for running server side code you need to add attribute runat="server" in the input control**